# Replace this lambda with a method reference. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
List<UUID> insrVrfyIds = insrVrfyObjsNew.stream().map(insrVrfy -> insrVrfy.getCustomerInsrVrfyId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For the following code i am getting a warning as i mentioned in title. Can anyone please explain me how to convert this.

here in the above code, i have a list of objects from that i want to extract all the primary keys using lambda expression.But i am getting the violation like "**Replace this lambda with a method reference. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<UUID> insrVrfyIds =
                    insrVrfyObjsNew.stream().map(CustomerInsrVrfy::getCustomerInsrVrfyId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This worked for the above.. That's my bad, it's working by replacing the variable (insrVrfy) with it's class name(CustomerInsrVrfy).

Answer (score 7):

Well it probably means that you could write it also like this:

```
List<UUID> insrVrfyIds = insrVrfyObjsNew.stream().map(InsrVrfy::getCustomerInsrVrfyId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I assumed there that your instance insrVrfy is of a class InsrVrfy so if I was mistaken please correct me.

[Here](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) you could read more about method reference.

Comment: No, it's not working. This i have tried, it is giving error like "insrVrfy cannot be resolved"

Comment: Could you tell me how is your insrVrfy class called?

Comment: thanks @pokemzok.. It's working.  Instead of class name i have used the same variable in method reference.